# Remote reconfig email clients from mail server

Tags: email, postfix

Today I got very interesting info. My friend use Outlook and Android Email application for using mails. Strange thing happed that Mail Administrator changed passwords for accounts, and without sending the new password both email clients change there settings. First I didn't think that was possible but that Administrator confirm that they did it that way remotely.

Is that even possible to change password in client configuration remotely? If so, how was that achieved?

Comment: in a local network or over internet? maybe it's handled by a domain controlled infrastructure?

Comment: nope. its on internet :O